# How to add CSS code inn to external JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a external CSS file and I have use CSS for the toggle. Where do I add following CSS codes?(In html file or the top of the external JavaScript file?)

```
.mystyle {
 
  background-color: green;
  color: white;

}
.mystyle1 {
 
  background-color: red;
  color: white;

}
```

Script.js

```
function myFunction(str) {

 var element = document.getElementById("btn1");
 var element1 = document.getElementById("btn2");
   
   
   if(str==1){
   
   
   element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
  element1.classList.remove("mystyle1");

   
    }else{
    
   element1.classList.toggle("mystyle1");
   element.classList.remove("mystyle");
  
  

    }
```

Comment: CSS is not valid JavaScript syntax. Why would you add it to a JavaScript file? Can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that *would* work as you seem to expect? Can you link the reference upon which you’re basing this implicit claim?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add in a html file if it is a external file.  [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Don't Mashup CSS with JS, keep those separately. you can try the below example:

```js
function myFunction(str) {
    var element = document.getElementById("btn1");
 var element1 = document.getElementById("btn2");
  
   if(str==1){
   element.classList.toggle("mystyle");
  element1.classList.remove("mystyle1");
    }else{
    
   element1.classList.toggle("mystyle1");
   element.classList.remove("mystyle");
   }
}
```

```css
.mystyle {
 
  background-color: green;
  color: white;

}
.mystyle1 {
 
  background-color: red;
  color: white;

}
```

```html
<div id="btn1" onClick="myFunction(1)">
btn1
</div>
<div id="btn2" onClick="myFunction(0)">
btn2
</div>
```

Comment: Where do I add this CSS code? In Html ? Because I am using external JavaScript

Comment: If you don't have any CSS file then add inline CSS:

instead of "element.classList" use

element.style.color = 'white';
element.style['background-color'] = 'green';
element1.style = {};

Answer (score -1):

1. You can not add CSS Directly to a JS Code
2. If you want to change CSS through JavaScript Code, you would need to add/remove each property using JS Code. For example, if you want to remove opacity from a certain element on click of another element, you can use:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('class_name');
element.style.opacity = '0';
```